# installing modules for perl

Tags: linux, perl, centos

```
perl -MCPAN -e "install 

Bundle::CPAN,ExtUtils::CBuilder,DBI,DBD::mysql,YAML,Params::Validate,
CGI,URI::Escape,Time::DaysInMonth,DateTime,DateTime::TimeZone,DateTime::Locale,
XML::Simple,Data::Dumper,Module::Build,Storable,Time::Zone,Date::Parse,Curses,
POE,Sys::Syslog,FCGI,DateTime::Set,DateTime::Event::Recurrence,DateTime::Incomplete,
Date::Language,DateTime::Format::Strptime,DBI::Shell,JSON,CGI::Fast,
Locale::gettext_pp,Text::Template,Mail::Sendmail,XML::Simple";
```

I have to execute this command to install some modules needed for a voip server.

This command takes too much time to run (hours). Is there a faster way to do it?
I'm on `CentOS 6.5`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A lot of those packages are probably available as pre-built CentOS packages, which would be substantially faster to install.

Perl packages on CentOS provide information about what perl modules they provide. For example, the `perl-DateTime` package provides the `perl(DateTime)` virtual package.  This means that if you take your list modules and transform it into a list of dependencies of the form `perl(Module::Name)`, you can pass that directly to yum.

Transforming your list, I get:

```
perl(Bundle::CPAN)
perl(ExtUtils::CBuilder)
perl(DBI)
perl(DBD::mysql)
perl(YAML)
perl(Params::Validate)
perl(CGI)
perl(URI::Escape)
perl(Time::DaysInMonth)
perl(DateTime)
perl(DateTime::TimeZone)
perl(DateTime::Locale)
perl(XML::Simple)
perl(Data::Dumper)
perl(Module::Build)
perl(Storable)
perl(Time::Zone)
perl(Date::Parse)
perl(Curses)
perl(POE)
perl(Sys::Syslog)
perl(FCGI)
perl(DateTime::Set)
perl(DateTime::Event::Recurrence)
perl(DateTime::Incomplete)
perl(Date::Language)
perl(DateTime::Format::Strptime)
perl(DBI::Shell)
perl(JSON)
perl(CGI::Fast)
perl(Locale::gettext_pp)
perl(Text::Template)
perl(Mail::Sendmail)
perl(XML::Simple)
```

If I put this in a file called "modules" and then run:

```
yum install $(cat modules)
```

I get a list of 45 packages to be installed.  Give that a shot.  It may not be comprehensive (you may still need to install a few with CPAN), but it should ultimately be much faster.

Comment: Thank you! 
i just had to run perl -MCPAN -e "install Bundle::CPAN, DBI::Shell,Storable"; after this.